# Using Java Reflections to retrieve member classes

Tags: java, reflection

I am using .getDeclaredClasses() method to retrieve all the classes that have been defined in  object. However, I am not able to retrieve anonymous classes defined in the class. Here is the code sample that I am testing:

```
public class TempCodes
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Ball b = new Ball()
    {
      public void hit()
      {
        System.out.println("You hit it!");
      }
    };
    b.hit();
  }

  interface Ball {
    void hit();
  }
}
```

and this is what my code does:

```
  memClass = className.getDeclaredClasses();
  if (memClass .length > 0) 
  {
        for (int index = 0 ; index < memClass .length ; index++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t" + memClass [index]);
        }
  }
```

Can anyone help me understand how to retrieve the anonymous class?

Regards,
darkie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679924/using-java-reflections-to-retrieve-member-classes

Comment: @Michael: Infinite loop!

Comment: @BalucC Gah, fail :). I was going for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654889/java-reflection-how-can-i-retrieve-anonymous-inner-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little help of the classpath:

```
final Class<?> cls = TempCodes.class;
String[] names = new File(cls.getResource("").toURI()).list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith(cls.getSimpleName());
    }
});
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Result:

```
TempCodes$1.class
TempCodes$Ball.class
TempCodes.class
```

You've to filter the desired information out yourself.

*Disclaimer: doesn't work well with JAR files, but the hint is clear enough: it's not possible with reflection. I would question the need for this and rethink the design or approach. Here are some topics of interest: [Java reflection: How can I retrieve anonymous inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654889/java-reflection-how-can-i-retrieve-anonymous-inner-classes) and [Accessing inner anonymous class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319765/accessing-inner-anonymous-class-members)*.